# Is it an Array or a String?

Tags: python, arrays, string

I'm given data that could be either a string or an array. I need to do different operations depending on which one it is, so my question is, how can I tell if an object is an array or a string in Python?

```
conn = boto.connect_sdb(AWSKey, AWSSecret)
item = conn.get_domain(dName).get_item(imagekey)
tags = item['tag']

tags == array or string?
```

Comment: Sounds like you're doing it wrong. Maybe post some sample code so that we can suggest a better design?

Comment: @jesse-j: So to clarify your Python script is getting some binary blob from an external source and you have to figure out the context to process it properly?

Comment: There's not much to it. I have a variable, and it's either a string or an array of strings. Is there a better design? Perhaps so, but I don't have control over it.

Comment: To me its not so much right or wrong, its what's appropriate for your situation depending on the context of your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "array" you mean list, then this should suffice:

```
if isinstance(data, list):
    # [...]
if isinstance(data, str):
    # "..."
```

If you mean array.array instead of a list:

```
if isinstance(data, array.array):
    # ...
```

Comment: You should almost never use `type(whatever)` in a comparison operation. Use `isinstance()` instead.

Answer (score 5):

Admittedly, the fact that strings are sequences is sometimes awkward. If you want to implement different behavior depending on if you are dealing with a "real" sequence or a string, you can use a construct like:

```
if isinstance(some_obj, basestring):
    # do string processing
else:
    # do sequence processing
```

You need to use `basestring` to correctly deal with unicode and non-unicode strings.

Comment: +1: PEP 8 clearly states "Object type comparisons should always use isinstance() instead of comparing types directly." Note, though, that `basestring` isn't available pre-2.3, so `isinstance(obj, (str, unicode))` is needed to support older interpreters.

Comment: This should probably be the accepted answer, as far as I can tell, isinstance(data, str) yeilds incorrect results much of the time.

Answer (score 1):

Use [this](http://linux.byexamples.com/archives/342/python-how-to-identify-the-type-of-your-variable/) guide to identify the type of your variable.

Comment: At first I thought the linked-to guide was a joke.  What's up with c.__class__.__name__==myclass.__name__ ?  Why not isinstance(c, myclass) ?

Answer (score 1):

A good way to handle this is to write a function that takes either a list or a single item, but always returns a list (returning a list with the single item in it in the latter case).

```
def listify(value):
    if isinstance(value, basestring):
        return [value]
    try:
        iter(value)
    except TypeError:
        return [value]
    return value
```

Then a quick `value = listify(value)` and you can pretend that you got a list all along.